# Enable CORS on API Gateway with Python CDK

Tags: python, api, cors, aws-cdk

I have an API Gateway defined in the python cdk that will accept CURL Restful requests to upload / read / delete files from an S3 bucket:

```
api = api_gw.RestApi(self, "file-api",
                  rest_api_name="File REST Service")
        
        file = api.root.add_resource("{id}")
        
        get_files_integration = api_gw.LambdaIntegration(handler,
                request_templates={"application/json": '{ "statusCode": "200" }'})
        post_file_integration = api_gw.LambdaIntegration(handler)
        get_file_integration = api_gw.LambdaIntegration(handler)
        delete_file_integration = api_gw.LambdaIntegration(handler)
        
        api.root.add_method("GET", get_files_integration, authorization_type=api_gw.AuthorizationType.COGNITO, authorizer=auth)
        file.add_method("POST", post_file_integration);     # POST /{id}
        file.add_method("GET", get_file_integration);       # GET /{id}
        file.add_method("DELETE", delete_file_integration); # DELETE /{id}
```

Is it possible to enable CORS on the API Gateway so that it will perform pre-flight checks and allow external access from a localhost on another machine?

I have attempted to use the existing add_core_preflight() method defined in the documentation I can find but believe this may no longer be valid as of CDK 2.0.

Comment: Were you able to find the functions?

Comment: I have, thank you. I have adapted my code accordingly but test user front-end is receiving the same error. I will mark your answer as correct but would it be acceptable to edit my question to include this new code in an attempt to de-bug?

Comment: I would probably post a separate question with the specific errors you're encountering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [`IResource.add_cors_preflight()`](https://constructs.dev/packages/aws-cdk-lib/v/2.12.0/api/IResource?lang=python&submodule=aws_apigateway#addCorsPreflight) does exactly this.

You can also specify default CORS config with the [`default_cors_preflight_options` attribute of `RestApi`](https://constructs.dev/packages/aws-cdk-lib/v/2.12.0/api/RestApi?lang=python&submodule=aws_apigateway#Initializer.parameter.defaultCorsPreflightOptions).

Here are the examples from the [docs](https://constructs.dev/packages/aws-cdk-lib/v/2.12.0?lang=python&submodule=aws_apigateway#cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors). They're in Typescript, but it will work the same in Python.

> The following example will enable CORS for all methods and all origins on all resources of the API:

```typescript
new apigateway.RestApi(this, 'api', {
  defaultCorsPreflightOptions: {
    allowOrigins: apigateway.Cors.ALL_ORIGINS,
    allowMethods: apigateway.Cors.ALL_METHODS // this is also the default
  }
})
```

> The following example will add an OPTIONS method to the myResource API resource, which only allows GET and PUT HTTP requests from the origin https://amazon.com.

```typescript
declare const myResource: apigateway.Resource;

myResource.addCorsPreflight({
  allowOrigins: [ 'https://amazon.com' ],
  allowMethods: [ 'GET', 'PUT' ]
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am unable to find these functions with CDK 2.10.0 (build e5b301f). Are these new functions from a more recent version?

Comment: No, they've been there for a while. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.RestApi.html#defaultcorspreflightoptions
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.Resource.html#addwbrcorswbrpreflightoptions